# Refresh button not updating database in SSMS although query is successfully completed :(

Tags: sql-server, ssms, objectbrowser

I'm running different queries in SSMS it shows "command completed successfully" but when I refresh the database, can't see the updates in databse.
Though you can see in image that I have created two database as **students** and **students1**. I have deleted the database **students1** and it shows that the command completed successfully but still **students1** is present in object explorer.

I'm a noob trying to learn sql but theses kind of glitchs are making the experience worst for me. Can you please help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s67Cx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right click on the "Databases" and press "Refresh". If you want to refresh list in the IntelliSense then in the query window press Crtrl+Shift+R

Comment: I've tried that but that didn't help anyway. Although I restarted the computer and now it's working fine. Thank you for a quick response.

Comment: I have the same issue in ssms 19.1
I have to restart ssms every time to fix this issue, Any Help?

Comment: it seems to me that I need to right-click on the 'Server' in order to fix this